# Android Tweet Api error on sign in

Tags: android, oauth, twitter

im facing an error in many tutorials out there, now im trying [this tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) and the problem is that when the explorer is opened, and i log in to twitter, when twitter asks to authorize i hit the Sign In Button, but nothing happens, like i said, i have this problem in many tutorials, not only this, what am i doing wrong?

BTW, i added this class to fix the NetworkOnUI Error:

```
private class Logintw extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Uri> {

    @Override
    protected Uri doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            requestToken = twitter
                    .getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Uri.parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL());
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * 
     * @see android.os.AsyncTask#onPostExecute(java.lang.Object)
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Uri result) {
        Intent in = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, result);
        in.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        getApplicationContext().startActivity(in
                );
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void loginToTwitter() {
    // Check if already logged in
    if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
        try {
        ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
        builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY);
        builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET);
        Configuration configuration = builder.build();
        TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
        twitter = factory.getInstance();
            TrequestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(TrequestToken.getAuthenticationURL())));
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Already Login to twitter!-----", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        TwitterLogin=true;
        checkloginstatus();

    }
}
```

Comment: are u use some library or jar file if u use some library or jar file then shold be declare in androidmanifist file

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
        if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
            String verifier = uri
                .getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);
            try {
                // Get the access token
                AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(TrequestToken, verifier);
                // Shared Preferences
                mPrefs=getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor e = mPrefs.edit();
                // After getting access token, access token secret store them in application preferences
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET,accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                // Store login status - true
                e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                e.commit(); // save changes
                long userID = accessToken.getUserId();
                User user = twitter.showUser(userID);
                String username = user.getName();
                TwitterLogin=true;
                checkloginstatus();
                new updateTwitterStatus().execute(username+ " is using http://AllPagesManager.com , Try it Now!!!");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // Check log for login errors
                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                    }
```

Comment: where am i supposed to put this please?

Comment: make simply one funcation in the name of logintotwitter and post above code of logintotwitter and then simle cope past above funcation onnewintent and check the callback url and also check the tokan if not solve the problem then send me ur code i will try

Comment: hi, i changed the tutorial to [this](http://blog.blundell-apps.com/sending-a-tweet/) and it works when i use the proyect itsefl, but when i integrate it with my proyect, when i sign in on twitter, i got this error:

`android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application`

Comment: ok i goted your mistake so kindly follow this toturial ([link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/)

Comment: ok i goted your mistake so kindly follow this toturial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/09/android-twitter-oauth-connect-tutorial/) try if got error the tell me